Android Studio freezes when navigating/finding usages/searching through Java files
Since I've updated to Android Studio Koala, I've been facing some issues regarding the stability of the Android Studio.
On the project that I'm working on I'm using both .kt and .java files, and usually when trying to navigate through Java files, the Studio seems to freeze, out of nowhere.
Specs & Info:
Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1
Build #AI-241.15989.150.2411.11948838, built on June 10, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.10+0-17.0.10b1087.21-11609105 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
OS:
macOS: Sonoma 14.5 (23F79)
Apple M2 Max chip, 64GB
What I've found until now that helps unfreezing it, is either kill the process (sometimes losing most of the code changes) or a combination of Save All, Sync project with Gradle Files, Reload all from Disk and Repair IDE actions.

I encountered the same problem and couldn't find proper fixes, but it seems that they fixed this in the latest patch: Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-241.18034.62.2411.12071903, built on July 11, 2024

Latest update seems to fix the issue.
